# Check whether device is connected to a VPN

Tags: ios, swift

I am able to check whether a device is connected to the internet using:

```
var connected: Bool = true
var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
    SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
}
var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) {
    connected = false
}
let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt2(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0

if isReachable && !needsConnection && connected {
    login(usernameTextField.text!, password: appPassword.text!, environment: environmentUrl)
} else {
    let alert = UIAlertView()
    alert.title = "No internet connection detected."
    alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
    alert.show()

    return
}
```

But is there any way of checking whether the device is connected to a VPN? The app that I am writing requires a VPN for access, so rather than allowing a user to attempt a login when not connected to a VPN, I would like to prompt them prior (better user experience in my opinion).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Perhaps instead of using the `sockaddr_in` you could target the tests on the exact host that you need to reach, won't tell you anything about VPN connection specifically but will keep working if such connection stops being a requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So there is no way of  knowing whether the iPad is connecting through a VPN or not?

Comment: Not that I know of, there must be at least private methods to do that though.

Comment: maybe trying to do SSL pinning? that would fail if it goes through any proxy (incl. VPN).

Answer (score 14):

I made it work for Swift 3/4 by using the following code:

```
private var isConnectedToVpn: Bool {
    if let settings = CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings()?.takeRetainedValue() as? Dictionary<String, Any>,
        let scopes = settings["__SCOPED__"] as? [String:Any] {
        for (key, _) in scopes {
         if key.contains("tap") || key.contains("tun") || key.contains("ppp") || key.contains("ipsec") {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I am using the code below (Swift 3 and Swift 4 compatible) to check the VPN connection on iOS devices which is working fine for me. Tested on two private VPNs and ExpressVPN, all using ipsec0 protocol.

```
func isVPNConnected() -> Bool {
    let cfDict = CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings()
    let nsDict = cfDict!.takeRetainedValue() as NSDictionary
    let keys = nsDict["__SCOPED__"] as! NSDictionary

    for key: String in keys.allKeys as! [String] {
        if (key == "tap" || key == "tun" || key == "ppp" || key == "ipsec" || key == "ipsec0" || key == "utun1" || key == "utun2") {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Also here is the gist link for the code - [Gist Link](https://gist.github.com/PramodJoshi/4faad4c91f7dcb4eb9b06be8390c01db)

Comment: The contains method might be better as it misses "utun2" etc

Comment: thanks for sharing! Do you also know if your app may get rejected if you try to have this code on production? It doesn't look super clean and sometimes they complain when you try to access data in this kind of ways.

Comment: @AlessandroFrancucci I wrote this for internal app so I can't say for sure if the Apple review team will reject but it is highly unlikely.

Comment: I believe this should use `takeUnretainedValue()` otherwise you incur a memory leak.

Answer (score 4):

A bit more modern way of detecting if a VPN connection is used is `NWPathMonitor`:

```swift
import Network

// You need to retain queue and monitor references somewhere
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "network.monitor")
let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
    let isUsingVPN = path.usesInterfaceType(.other)
    // ...
}
monitor.start(queue: queue)
```

From the docs, the `other` interface type stands for

> communication over virtual networks or networks of unknown types.

This gave me the correct results when testing with a standard VPN connection as well as with shadowsocks.

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between checking if a VPN is installed (which is what the earlier answers detect) vs. checking whether traffic is being routed over a VPN (or other proxy). If you are only checking if a VPN is installed, it can have a negative impact on users who have 3rd party VPN apps installed that only filter some (but not all) traffic, which is common for enterprises.

Here's some sample code for checking if traffic to a particular host is being routed over a VPN/transparent proxy or not.

```
import Foundation
import Network

func main() {
    
    // Check if connection to host is being routed over transparent proxy (such as VPN) 
    let c = NWConnection(host: "domainname.com", port: 443, using: .tcp)
    c.stateUpdateHandler = { state in
        if (state == .ready) {
            if (c.currentPath?.usesInterfaceType(.other) == true) {
                print("Connection is over transparent proxy")
            } else {
                print("Connection is not over transparent proxy")
            }
        }
    }
    c.start(queue: .main)
    dispatchMain()
}

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

ObjC:

```c
#include <ifaddrs.h>

- (BOOL)isVPNOn
{
    BOOL flag = NO;
    NSString *version = [UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion;
    // need two ways to judge this.
    if (version.doubleValue >= 9.0)
    {
        NSDictionary *dict = CFBridgingRelease(CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings());
        NSArray *keys = [dict[@"__SCOPED__"] allKeys];
        for (NSString *key in keys) {
            if ([key rangeOfString:@"tap"].location != NSNotFound ||
                [key rangeOfString:@"tun"].location != NSNotFound ||
                [key rangeOfString:@"ipsec"].location != NSNotFound ||
                [key rangeOfString:@"ppp"].location != NSNotFound){
                flag = YES;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        struct ifaddrs *interfaces = NULL;
        struct ifaddrs *temp_addr = NULL;
        int success = 0;

        // retrieve the current interfaces - returns 0 on success
        success = getifaddrs(&interfaces);
        if (success == 0)
        {
            // Loop through linked list of interfaces
            temp_addr = interfaces;
            while (temp_addr != NULL)
            {
                NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s" , temp_addr->ifa_name];
                if ([string rangeOfString:@"tap"].location != NSNotFound ||
                    [string rangeOfString:@"tun"].location != NSNotFound ||
                    [string rangeOfString:@"ipsec"].location != NSNotFound ||
                    [string rangeOfString:@"ppp"].location != NSNotFound)
                {
                    flag = YES;
                    break;
                }
                temp_addr = temp_addr->ifa_next;
            }
        }

        // Free memory
        freeifaddrs(interfaces);
    }

    return flag;
}
```

ref: [RealReachability/RealReachability.m - GitHub](https://github.com/dustturtle/RealReachability/blob/1f549b7d5d44dd1d17e6c5754084eaf54737011a/RealReachability/RealReachability.m)